# How get values from Material UI inputs when there is unknown amount of inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating form where user can add documents. Each document have 6 inputs (select, text input, date input, file input). User can add as much as he want documents, for example: some users need to add 4 documents, some - 20 and more.

So I'm trying to figure out how to get values from all inputs, when I can't to set values to states.

I'm using Material UI, maybe is there easy way to get values?

Comment: You just want to get an array of strings? Without knowing which input has each value?

Comment: no, each inputs block ( 6 inputs) depends to one document and they describe that document, so I need to know values of that block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a controlled input

To make this dynamic you could set state as an object then just setState adding keys as you need them

const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});

...

const handleChange = (inputId) => (e) => setInputValues({
...inputValues,
[inputId] : e.target.value
})

...

<input
value={inputValues[inputId]}
onChange{handleChange(inputId)}
/>